# Remember me checkbox test case for login functionality using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor

1. If remember me checkbox is checked while login, browser should remember  user credentials. Website homepage should load directly for next time.
2. If remember me checkbox is unchecked while login, browser should not remember user credentials. Website should go to login page for next time.

It will be helpful to know how to implement these test case with protractor.

Comment: Please let us know what u have already tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor loads up a fresh, unladen instance of a browser each time you run your test suites. Cookies, settings, security settings and so forth are forgotten. If you want to test a "Remember Me" checkbox long-term, you'll have to use the following in your Protractor config file:

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['--user-data-dir=some/file/path']
        }
}
```

This will preserve your cookies and settings in between runs, so that the next time you run the test everything will be there.

A short-term test would be more dependable. All you'll need to do for that is:

Test 1) Log in after checking the box. `Browser.get` another web page (google.com or something). `Browser.get` your login page and `expect` that the login has been bypassed (as indicated by the URL or an element on the page).

Test 2) Log in without checking the box. `Browser.get` another web page (google.com or something). `Browser.get` your login page and `expect` that the login is not bypassed (as indicated by the URL or an element on the page).